# Count Array within a cell python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, count

I have arrays within my data frame that I need to count.

This is the code I'm using:

```
indi = data_1.query("'2016-11-22' <= login_date <= '2016-12-22'").groupby(['employer_key','account_id','login_date']).count().reset_index()
indi_1 = indi.groupby(['employer_key']).account_id.unique().reset_index()
indi_1
```

which gives me this:

```
    employer_key        account_id
0   boeing              [17008601, 17008645, 17008698, 17008952, 17009...]
1   dell_inc            [10892711, 10892747, 10894032, 10894676, 10894...]
2   google              [9215462, 9216605, 9217052, 9218693, 9222937, ...]
3   sprint_corporation  [9858036, 9858809, 9859191, 9859350, 9859498, ...]
4   walmart             [2515412, 2517367, 2519765, 2520049, 2526763, ...]
```

I want to count the numbers in the array so it looks like this:

```
  employer_key         account_id
0   boeing             5000
1   dell_inc           289
2   google             789
3   sprint_corporation 154670
4   walmart            4689
```

How can I do this? I'm using pandas. I'm also very new to python, so simpler the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the *account_id* column contains lists, you can use `str.len()` to calculate the number of elements in each cell:

```
df['account_id_count'] = df.account_id.str.len()
df
```

[image]